# HttpWebRequest times out on the second call to the Web Server

Tags: c#, python, .net, httpwebrequest

I've got a very strange problem here:

There is a RESTfull web service on a `Python Paste` web server, a WPF .net application makes a  http POST request to the server every 2 seconds. The problem is that on the second call to the server, the request times out! sometimes later (say forth or fifth) requests work again and later again I get this "time out" exception!

The IntelliTrace shows that there was a blocked operation in `ws2_32.dll`:

> A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to
>   WSACancelBlockingCall

I simulated the REST web server on the IIS using `asp.net` and the problem no longer exists, so I assume it might be the Python server config! But the Python Web Server works normally when I make the request from within the browser!

However I tried different things in the .net client application:

- I have increased the ServicePoint's `DefaultConnectionLimit`:

  `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;`
- I created a new thread for any new request to the server and aborted it when request is done!
- I created a new `AppDomain` before any request and explicitly unloaded it when process is done!
- Tried different http request headers: `connection=keep-alive, accept=*`

None of the above seems to work! However the funny part is that when I set a break-point to the `GetRequestStream()` line in VS 2012, the request **dos not** timeout and works properly!

Debugging the .net managed code using reflection I figured that the unmanaged `recv` method of the `ws2_32.dll` causes the operation to block and hence the web request times out!

Here's the C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine(PostData());
        }
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string PostData()
{
    try
    {
        var response = "";
        var httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://remote_address");
        httpRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 500;
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpRequest.Timeout = 5000;

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write("req=" + "[some parameters]");
        }

        using (WebResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var data = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data, Encoding.UTF8);
                response = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            httpResponse.Close();
        }

        return response;
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return "time out!";
    }
}
```

Is there **anything** I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue with disabling `Expect100Continue` header:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

According to the `HTTP 1.1` protocol, when this header is sent, client requests that use the POST method expect to receive a `100-Continue` response from the server to indicate that the client should send the data to be posted.

Having this property set to `true` (which is the default behavior of .Net) the data is not sent with the initial request. Instead, this header is sent to the web server which responds with `100-Continue` if implemented correctly. However, **not all web servers handle this correctly**, including the server to which I am attempting to post data. I sniffed the headers using `Fiddler` and noticed that my code does send this header, while the `Python Paste` does not!